# auto answer to a message box on updating links

Tags: vba, excel

Hi have a macro that open some excel files, take some rows and close the file.
Everything works like a charm but I need to add a small feature. 
On some of the files, once open, I see the message about some reference to external files missing and the option to update or not the sources. 
The following is a picture of the message.
[image]
I need to click each time on "don't update" and I'd like to authomatize this action while the macro runs.

How to do it? From my research I have found how to dismiss completely messages from excel while the macro runs but I'm not sure this will solve my issue

Comment: This is a security feature so disabling alerts may not work but I would start by tring `application.displayalerts = false` (turn back on before exiting sub)

Comment: If you use [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) there is a specific parameter for that (the second one)

Comment: `Workbooks.Open filename:=... UPDATELINKS:=FALSE` is another option.

Comment: with workbooks.open filename,0 it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only reading data so open them read only and tell VBA not to update the links so it will not ask you that at all:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyWorkBook, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Where `WB` is the workbook that gets opened and `MyWorkBook` is the full name (path of the workbook) e.g. `C:\MyDrive\MyWorkbook.xlsx`

Comment: yes, this is exactly what other users said in the comments and solved my issue

Comment: I added some more nuances to it